# Building all solutions in a folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch script that will build all *.sln files in a folder using Visual Studio 2012's devenv.exe and I am running into some trouble.   With the following code I am getting ""forfiles" is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

I am executing this from a computer running Windows 7 Enterprise N 64-bit.

```
@echo off

SET executablePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
SET buildConfig = "Release"

cls

forfiles /m *.sln /c "cmd %executablePath% @file /build %buildConfig%"
```

Answer (score 0):

My batch is a little poor, but if you have Powershell installed on the PC you could use something like this:

```
$SLNDirectory = "<Path_to_SLN_Files>"
$executablePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
$buildConfig = "Release"
Clear
$Files = Get-ChildItem $SLNDirectory
Foreach($File in $Files){
$Extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($File).ToString()
    If ($Extension -eq ".sln"){
        $theFile = $File.Name
        [Array]$SLNFiles +=$theFile 
    }
}

Foreach($SLNFile in $SLNFiles){
    & "$executablePath $SLNFile /build $buildConfig"
}
```

Comment: This would probably work.  I was trying to use a batch file because some of the developer machines apparently don't have Powershell (or at least the file association set up).

Comment: You could change the file association using the assoc command: assoc .ps1=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe then see if you can run the .ps1 file. Assoc though needs to be ran from the command prompt with Admin privileges. As long as the operating system is Windows Vista or above Powershell should be installed. If they have XP it can be installed, but probably not worth the effort from the sounds of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Batch script):

```
@echo off

SET "executablePath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
SET "buildConfig=Release"

cls

for %%i in (*.sln) do cmd /c "%executablePath%" "%%~i" /build %buildConfig%
```